# Timer stopping after 0.29

Tags: javascript, timer

```html
    <head>
    <script>
        window.setInterval(function(){timer()},100);
        function timer()
            {
                document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=
               (parseInt(document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML*100)+1)/100;
            }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="timer">0.000</div>
    </body>
```

As you see, timer counts only up to `0.29`.

Why is it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's because of the way floating point math works coupled with your `parseInt()`. Refer to [Is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

When it reaches `0.29`, it does `0.29 x 100`, which you're expecting to result in `29` but actually it is:

```
console.log(0.29 * 100);
28.999999999999996
```

Next, you convert it to an integer using `parseInt()` which results in `28` (removing all of the decimal places), finally you add `1` and divide by `100` making the result `0.29` and this is repeated on each tick of the timer, the number can't increase.

It would be better to store the raw value as a variable and output it using `.toFixed(2)`, instead of using the number on the UI as the source. Like this:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6TeQ/)**

```
var num = 0.00;

window.setInterval(function () {
    timer();
}, 100);

function timer() {
    num = ((num * 100) + 1) / 100;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = num.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: It should also be noted that `parseInt` is redundant because `*` casts to numeric anyway (and in this case the function is harmful)

Comment: `parseInt` isn't redundant here, it is the source of the problem because it removes the decimal places which ultimately causes the number to stick at `0.29`. If you remove the `parseInt()`, the counter continues beyond `0.29` (albeit showing the full decimal places).

Comment: Its use is misguided because the thing being parsed is already a number. Anyway, missing the point ;)

Comment: Yes it is already a number, but a float not an int. If it was `parseFloat()` then it would be completely redundant.

Comment: As far as the logic goes, `x.innerHTML*100` was *supposed* to be an int (obviously it isn't due to float errors) and yet was still being passed to `parseInt`.

Comment: Agreed, in OP's mind it was supposed to be an int :)

Comment: @MrCode - +1 This kind of bug is so common.